# Replacing strings in Typescript file with gulp-replace

Tags: angular, gulp-replace, typescript2.2

I'm attempting to insert a build version into my Angular 2 component file, using a gulp-replace task. I'm retrieving the build version from the process variable `process.env.npm_package_version`. This part is working, as I am able to log the value to the console and get the expected value. However, the gulp-replace portion of my task is not working. I am executing the `replace` task before anything else.

### The task:

```ts
const replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('replace', () => {
    let version = `${process.env.npm_package_version}`;
    gulp.src('src/app/app.component.ts')
        .pipe(replace('buildVersion', version))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

### The source:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app/app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app/app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {}
    app = { version: "buildVersion", currentYear: new Date().getFullYear() };
}
```

Comment: your gulp dest looks a bit off. is ./ your build folder?

Comment: It is. I had wrongfully assumed that the destination was relative to the source. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gulp dest` is wrong. Glad it's fixed.

By the way, if your intention is:

1 - to copy to your build folder

All good, job done, but if your intention is:

2 - to overwrite original

then your logic will not work the second time round coz you would have replaced the string "buildVersion" in which case you may need to replace on a regex such as /\d\d.\d\d.\d\d/

And then the buildVersion in your original file can just be:

00.00.00

Then when it is replaced with:

01.01.44

the regex will still work the second time round.

The reason I mentioned it is because you mentioned about the destination being relative to the source which suggests an overwrite to me.

Comment: Not long after, I discovered the same thing you suggested, that the overwrite would cause the replace to fail the next time it was called. To solve this, I used a regex string `/(version: )".+"/` and replacement `$1"${process.env.npm_package_version}"`, so as to only replace the string following the version field. Thanks again!